# Calculate the quantile for a mixed pdf

Tags: sampling, density-function, mixed-model

I am trying to draw random numbers that follow a two-part pdf

a) $|x|< x_0: f(x)=\text{constant}\quad \to \quad F(p)=a+(b-a)p$

b) $|x|> x_0: f(x)=\exp(-|x|)\quad \to \quad F(p)=-\ln(1-p)$

that is the probability is constant between $(-x_0,x_0)$ and falls exponentially outside it.

Knowing the quantile functions $F(p)$ ($0\leq p\leq 1$) of the pdf, how can I construct the quantile that describes the above pdf comprised of two parts?

Comment: Your formulas are inconsistent: for instance, in part (b), $F$ is not the quantile function for $f$. ($F$ assigns zero probability to negative numbers whereas $f$ is symmetric around $0$.)  This leaves the question indeterminate.  Please edit your question to fix up the mathematical problems or at least provide more information so that the question becomes unambiguous.

Comment: It seems like you're maybe confusing together the cdf with its inverse. First, try drawing a picture of the pdf, the cdf, and the inverse of the cdf (the quantile function). Once you can get the cdf right, it's easier to get its inverse right.

Comment: The way I was trying to do this is as follows: calculate the CDF (by integrating), then find the inverse function. Now I was just confused how to "stick them together" since I only draw p in [0,1].
@Glen_b When I am drawing random numbers accordingly to a given pdf I always use its quantile function. I think this is correct since it is related to the inverse of the pdf but please correct me if I am wrong!
That is of course, correct, I was thinking about calculating only x >0 first, then mirroring it! Would that work?

Comment: Take some care. One reason for suggesting you write the cdf was that I was hoping you'd see that your *density* is probably not correctly specified (I suspect you're aiming to have continuity at $\pm x_0$ - is that the case?  If so, your $f$ is wrong. As I said, somewhere earlier, draw it.). If you don't get that right you're wasting your time jumping several steps further along.

Comment: Thanks @Glen_b now I understand what you meant! It works like a charm!

Comment: Now that you have it clearly understood, I'll leave more details so the question has an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the actual pdf required:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
  c\quad &|x|\leq x_0\\
   c_1 \exp(-|x|)\quad &|x|> x_0
\end{cases}$$
that is the probability is constant between $(-x_0,x_0)$ and falls exponentially outside it, and where $c_1$ and $c$ are such that the pdf is continuous and integrates to 1.

That is, we have the conditions that $c_1\exp(-x_0) = c$; i.e. $c_1 = c\exp(x_0)$ and that the $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx = 1$.

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx 
&=& 2c\left( \int_{0}^{x_0} 1 dx  +  \exp(x_0)\int_{x_0}^\infty \exp(-x) dx \right)\\
&=& 2c\left( x|_{0}^{x_0} - \exp(x_0)\exp(-x)|_{x_0}^\infty \right)\\
&=& 2c\left( x_0 - \exp(x_0)[0-\exp(-x_0)] \right)\\
&=& 2c( x_0 +1 )
\end{eqnarray}

Implying $c=\frac{1}{2( x_0 +1 )}$. Here's $f$ for $x_0=1$ (black) and $x_0=2$ (green):

[image]

As a quick check on our algebra, via approximate numerical integration the area under both curves seems to be 1 to about the right number of figures.

Now we have the pdf right, we can write the cdf:

$$F(x)=
\begin{cases}
c\exp(x+x_0)&x\leq -x_0\\
1/2+cx& -x_0<x<x_0\\
1/2+cx_0+c(1-\exp(x_0-x))& x\geq x_0
\end{cases}$$

(though there are perhaps better ways to write that last term; I'm not going to investigate that here)

Here are the corresponding cdfs for the above two cases:

[image]

Here's the quantile function, $Q(p) = F^{-1}(p)$:

$$Q(p) = 
\begin{cases}
\ln(p/c)-x_0  & 0<p\leq 1/2 -cx_0\\
(p-.5)/c      & 1/2-cx_0<p<1/2+cx_0\\
x_0-\ln(1-[(p - 0.5)/c - x_0]) & 1/2+cx_0\leq p<1
\end{cases}$$

and a drawing of the inverse cdf for the same cases as above:

[image: inverse cdf]

I wouldn't have got these right without drawing diagrams along the way, especially of $f$ and $F$.